# SBCL: Fixnum Optimizations

Tags: optimization, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to get more speed out of a little quadratic solver by using optimizations and fixnums. Here's my code:

```
 1: (defun solve-x (d)
 2:   (declare (optimize (speed 3))
 3:               (type fixnum d))
 4:   (let ((x 1) (y 1))
 5:     (declare (type fixnum x y))
 6:     (loop while (/= (- (* x x) (* d y y)) 1) do
 7:       (if (> (- (* x x) (* d y y)) 1)
 8:         (incf y)
 9:         (incf x)))
10:     (list x y)))
```

The SBCL compiler seems to have trouble optimizing lines 6 and 7 correctly. I'm getting lots of warnings like this one:

```
forced to do GENERIC-- (cost 10)
      unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 2) because:
      The first argument is a (INTEGER 1 21267647932558653957237540927630737409), not a FIXNUM.
      The second argument is a (INTEGER
                                -98079714615416886892398913872502479823289163909206900736
                                98079714615416886871131265939943825866051622981576163327), not a FIXNUM.
      The result is a (VALUES
                       (INTEGER
                        -98079714615416886871131265939943825866051622981576163326
                        98079714615416886913666561805061133780526704836837638145)
                       &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES FIXNUM &REST T).
      unable to do inline (signed-byte 64) arithmetic (cost 5) because:
      The first argument is a (INTEGER 1 21267647932558653957237540927630737409), not a (SIGNED-BYTE
                                                                                         64).
      The second argument is a (INTEGER
                                -98079714615416886892398913872502479823289163909206900736
                                98079714615416886871131265939943825866051622981576163327), not a (SIGNED-BYTE
                                                                                                  64).
      The result is a (VALUES
                       (INTEGER
                        -98079714615416886871131265939943825866051622981576163326
                        98079714615416886913666561805061133780526704836837638145)
                       &OPTIONAL), not a (VALUES (SIGNED-BYTE 64) &REST T).
      etc.
```

Don't know, where to continue. I already tried to insert 'the fixnum' around multiplications, divisions and subtractions, but it only got worse.

Any ideas, how to make this fast?

Comment: I found an additional answer of how to do this by doing bitwise asking of results. See the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58424422/how-to-convince-lisp-sbcl-to-do-inline-fixnum-arithmetic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sure that the numbers will not overflow at any point, you can add `(SAFETY 0)` to the optimizations. Also add `(THE FIXNUM ...)` around the calculations to tell SBCL that you want the result to be treated as a fixnum. The three argument `*` should be split to two separate calls.

Your code is currently calculating `(- (* x x) (* d y y))` twice in the loop. You should assign it to a variable instead. Also notice that since only `X` or `Y` changes in the loop, it's unnecessary to calculate the other part again (I don't know what those calculations are, so I just called them `FOO`, `BAR` and `QUUX`).

```
(defun solve-x (d)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type fixnum d))
  (let ((x 1) (y 1))
    (declare (type fixnum x y))
    (loop with foo of-type fixnum = (* x x)
          with bar of-type fixnum = (* (the fixnum (* d y)) y)
          for quux of-type fixnum = (- foo bar)
          while (/= quux 1)
          do (if (> quux 1)
                 (setf y (1+ y)
                       bar (* (the fixnum (* d y)) y))
                 (setf x (1+ x)
                       foo (* x x))))
    (list x y)))
```

To avoid having to write the formulas twice, you could use the `#n=` reader macro. `X` and `Y` can also be moved to the parameter list as `&AUX` variables to get rid of the `LET` and second `DECLARE`.

```
(defun solve-x (d &aux (x 1) (y 1))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type fixnum d x y))
  (loop with foo of-type fixnum = #1=(* x x)
        with bar of-type fixnum = #2=(* d (the fixnum (* y y)))
        for quux of-type fixnum = (- foo bar)
        while (/= quux 1)
        do (if (> quux 1)
               (setf y (1+ y)
                     bar #2#)
               (setf x (1+ x)
                     foo #1#)))
  (list x y))
```

Since `X` and `Y` always increase by one, you could avoid some multiplication by incrementing the previous value.

```
(defun solve-x (d &aux (x 1) (y 1))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type fixnum d x y))
  (loop with foo of-type fixnum = 1
        with bar of-type fixnum = d
        for quux of-type fixnum = (- foo bar)
        while (/= quux 1)
        do (if (> quux 1)
               (setf bar (+ bar (the fixnum (* d y)))
                     y (1+ y)
                     bar (+ bar (the fixnum (* d y))))
               (setf foo (+ foo x)
                     x (1+ x)
                     foo (+ foo x))))
  (list x y))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `fixnum` is not a very useful type.  In particular, if `a` and `b` are `fixnum`s then `(* a b)` may well not be: consider `(* most-positive-fixnum most-positive-fixnum)`: this is not a `fixnum`.

So what you need to do is declare the arguments to have good types: in particular types which are enough smaller than a `fixnum` that the arithmetic will not overflow into `bignum`s.  Assuming you're using a 64-bit platform this is reasonably easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how large those numbers can get in your application but by declaring them to be (signed-byte 31) can result in another 25-ish % speed gain.

```
(deftype int31 (&optional (bits 31)) `(signed-byte ,bits))
(defun solve-x (d &aux (x 1) (y 1))
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type int31 d x y))
  (loop with foo of-type int31 = 1
        with bar of-type int31 = d
        for quux of-type int31 = (- foo bar)
        while (/= quux 1)
        do (if (> quux 1)
               (setf bar (+ bar (the int31 (* d y)))
                     y (1+ y)
                     bar (+ bar (the int31 (* d y))))
               (setf foo (+ foo x)
                     x (1+ x)
                     foo (+ foo x))))
  (list x y))
```